# Extract size of the image embedded in a PDF

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I have an image embedded in a PDF file. I was able to extract the resolution of the image. However, if i crop the PDF using iTextsharp and a part of the image is cropped in the process. The new image continues to have the same resolution. By resolution I mean the dimension in the form of Width x Height. The cropped image is supposed to have a smaller size. How can I extract the size of the image in inches, if possible, so that I can differentiate the original image from the cropped pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded images in PDFs are never "cropped" in the sense that the "cropped-away" parts are gone forever. They are only cropped in the sense that these parts are hidden or masked.

If the image data inside the PDF say `/Height 216` and `/Width 288` then this is the size in **Pixels** (not inches or any other length unit). And "resolution" is then secondary:

- if the PDF environment commands that this image should be rendered onto a square of 3x4 inches, its resolution in this moment is 72x72 dpi.
- if the PDF environment commands that this image should be rendered onto a square of 1.5x2 inches, its resolution in this moment is 144x144 dpi.

However it can well be that the image is only partially visible ("cropped"), maybe because half of it is rendering beyond the page borders...

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Really helped. Is there a way I can determine the width and height of the "visible" part of the image in a cropped pdf?

Comment: @user1512781: Yes there is: Look at it. :-))  -- Seriously: no, I don't know of a *simple* way to determine this.